# Microsoft Azure : Updating Modules in the automation account

Tags: azure, runbook

In Azure portal, When I tried to export the runbook in automation accounts to a different subscription, there was an error and when I tried reaching out the Microsoft they say the error was because I was using Old Modules in the Assests. How do I update the Old Modules?

Answer (score 0):

The global modules that are in there should be updated automatically by Msft/Azure - I just looked at mine and they're all dated yesterday.

Are there any "non global" modules that you or another subscription user has added in the past, those you need to maintain yourself, and hence update them via the portal when you need to.

Comment: I didn't create any of those modules, all of them were default modules present when I created the automation account. I just created the 'assests' in the automation account which I was able to move.  So, as I didn't create the modules inside the automation account, can it be considered as "global modules" ? which should be updated by Msft Azure?          Thanks.